# Save output of pandas dataframe to file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want to save an array that was created using get_dummies function in jupyter notebook.
Is there a way to save the whole array(1543x745) preferably as an excel or any other editable file?
If not can someone suggest another program I can run the code and get me a similar (visually) result that can be saved?

[image: part of the array I need to save]

Comment: Do you need `dummies.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)` ?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for your answer, I am trying this using both dummies.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
and dummies.to_excel(r'file.xlsx', index=False)
but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: So problem is find saved file?

Comment: There is error?

Comment: @jezrael No but it's probably something I am doing wrong. I created an empty excel file and that's the file I am trying to save into. Is that not what I am supposed to do?

Comment: OK, it is wrong way. If use `dummies.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)` it create new file filled by data, not filled existing file